# grid "proof" for commutativity of multiplication

Tags: proof-theory

In this write-up by Tim Gowers on why multiplication is commutative,

[https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/commutative.html](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ewtg10/commutative.html)

he gives a physical grid model to which multiplication corresponds and says - "This argument, compelling as it is, doesn't quite qualify as a mathematical proof"

Why, precisely, doesn't this qualify as a mathematical proof ?

Comment: This is a good question, but I have voted to migrate to math.stackexchange, as it not on-topic for MO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a semi-formal point of view, it doesn't qualify as a mathematical proof because:

1. it is unclear whether it is speaking of the single identity $395\times 428=428\times 395$ or whether the author claims of having given a general argument;
2. it hasn't been shown how the properties of *being a rectangular grid* and *rotating by ninety degrees* work together towards the result of preserving the cardinality of a (the?) rectangular grid.

It should be pointed out that modern mathematical formalism generally demands that, with a few notable classes of exceptions, a proof should be founded in the language of some set theory, the most common being ZFC, and that the argument of interest does not immediately qualify as such.

Comment: What are (some of) these notable classes of exceptions ?

Comment: I don't know much about them, but I think a good number of topics in mathematical logic do not gain much (if not lose something) in being formulated as a model inside some set theory. Also, the constructions of category theory quickly exceed the possibility set theories generally have of treating things as "objects".